# How to change dataframe from long to wide shape without losing duplicated values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, dummy-variable

I have given example dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
            'company_name': ['do holdings co', 'real estate b.v.', 'real estate b.v.','real coiffure', 'real coiffure', 'elendom', 'theatre media ltd'],
            'sector_1': ['Industrials', 'Finance', 'Finance','Consumer', 'Consumer','Real Estate', 'Media'],
            'company_country': ['USA', 'Poland', 'Poland','USA','USA', 'Poland', 'Canada'],
            'keyword': ['holding', 'real', 'estate','real','coiffure', 'elendom', 'theatre'],
            'value': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            'sector': ['Finance', 'Real Estate', 'Real Estate', 'Real Estate', 'Consumer', 'Real Estate', 'Media']
})
```

I was checking if keywords exists in a company name, if they do - I was assigning them matching sector (column sector, sector_1 - please ignore for now).

I have a list of keywords and as you can see they duplicate in a keyword column - because I was checking per each company. I already filtered out the keyword with 0 occurrences.

I would like to change the table to wide format, but where we have duplication with key words - then assign two sectors, the results should be as below:

```py
df_results = pd.DataFrame({
            'company_name': ['do holdings co', 'real estate b.v.', 'real coiffure', 'elendom', 'theatre media ltd'],
            'sector_1': ['Industrials', 'Finance','Consumer', 'Real Estate', 'Media'],
            'company_country': ['USA', 'Poland','USA', 'Poland', 'Canada'],
            'holding': [1,0,0,0,0],
            'real': [0,1,1,0,0],
            'estate': [0,1,0,0,0],
            'coiffure': [0,0,1,0,0],
            'elendom': [0,0,0,1,0],
            'theatre': [0,0,0,0,1],
            'sector': ['Finance', ['Real Estate', 'Real Estate'],['Real Estate', 'Consumer'], 'Real Estate', 'Media']
    })
```

I have a problem approaching this task, appreciate the help.

EDIT:

This is what I've been trying, still not perfect but almost there:

```py
df_wide = pd.crosstab(index=df['company_name'], columns=df['keyword'], values=df['value'], aggfunc='sum')
df_wide['sector'] = df.groupby('company_name')['sector'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
df_results = pd.merge(df_wide, df[['company_name','sector_1','company_country']], on='company_name', how='left')
```

Comment: Without more context to your problem, I would doubt that your target dataframe `df_results` is a good approach. That's because it is of a very non-standard data structure. Can you provide more information on how you will use `df_results`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), and [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```py
# Group rows
df = df.groupby(["company_name"]).agg(list).drop(columns="value")

# Remove duplicated values
for col in ["sector_1", "company_country"]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))[0])

# Remove lists of one value in 'sector' column
df["sector"] = df["sector"].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)

# Get dummies and add columns to dataframe
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["keyword"].apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1).drop(columns="keyword").reset_index()

# Reorder columns
df = df.reindex([col for col in df.columns if col != "sector"] + ["sector"], axis=1)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

        company_name     sector_1 company_country  coiffure  elendom  estate  \
0     do holdings co  Industrials             USA         0        0       0   
1            elendom  Real Estate          Poland         0        1       0   
2      real coiffure     Consumer             USA         1        0       0   
3   real estate b.v.      Finance          Poland         0        0       1   
4  theatre media ltd        Media          Canada         0        0       0   

   holding  real  theatre                      sector  
0        1     0        0                     Finance  
1        0     0        0                 Real Estate  
2        0     1        0     [Real Estate, Consumer]  
3        0     1        0  [Real Estate, Real Estate]  
4        0     0        1                       Media
```